# php help to replace/add relative path

Tags: php, media, m3u8

I am trying to add relative path to a m3u8

Here is my original m3u8

```
     #EXTM3U
     #EXT-X-VERSION:3
     #EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO
     #EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:29
     #EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:4476
     #EXTINF:10.0,
     media-mvexqubfd_4476.ts
     #EXTINF:10.0,
     media-mvexqubfd_4477.ts
     #EXTINF:10.0,
     media-mvexqubfd_4478.ts
```

I want to convert this to:

```
 #EXTM3U
 #EXT-X-VERSION:3


  #EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO
     #EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:29
     #EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:4476
     #EXTINF:10.0,
     path-to-media/media-mvexqubfd_4476.ts
     #EXTINF:10.0,
     path-to-media/media-mvexqubfd_4477.ts
     #EXTINF:10.0,
     path-to-media/media-mvexqubfd_4478.ts
```

I am trying to explode using \n and then reading each item in array and adding the relative path, But i think there is a better and simpler way to do it, Can someone point me

Comment: its come like an string firstly?

Comment: Can you please post the code you're using that isn't working, or [a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)? Thanks!

Comment: A simple regex would do `/^(?!#)/m` or even `~^(?=[^/#]+$)~m`